# C# EF Core - Correct way to update an entity for console application

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, console-application

I have a console app that loops through table on a webpage and saves some data.

I initialize db as below

```
services.AddDbContext<HemBotDbContext>(opt =>
{
    opt.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=TheDatabaseName");
});
```

Basically my database operation is (`_dbContext` is injected)

```
var existing = _dbContext.Stuff.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == stuff.Id);

if (existing == null)
{
     // works ok, add entity
}
else
{
    existing.LastSeen = DateTime.Now;
    _dbContext.Entry(existing).State = EntityState.Modified;
    _dbContext.SaveChanges()
}
```

Alternative #2:

```
existing.LastSeen = DateTime.Now;
_dbContext.SaveChanges()
```

Alternative #3:

```
existing.LastSeen = DateTime.Now;
_dbContext.Stuff.Update(existing)
_dbContext.SaveChanges()
```

I either get the message that the entity "is already tracked" or LastSeen date never gets saved.

I've read somewhere that it was a special case with console apps that they should not have the default DI scope, but I could not find the correct scope.

This can't be this tricky, it feels like I'm missing something basic here :) please help. We are talking a few thousand rows and this error occurs "sometimes", but quite often

I'm a bit hesitant to create a context every time I update a value, it seems wasteful, but is this the way to go?

**So the question is, how do I do this correctly, since none of the above works?** You don't need to comment the alternatives, its just "what I have tried"

Comment: I would consider manipulating entity state in alternative 1 to be antipattern. Unless you mess with untracked entities, just update the properties you want and call dbContext.SaveChanges(). It's smart enough to figure out what changed. So, alternative 2 is the correct one. Console app should have no effect on how that works. If it doesn't, it's something else in your code that you didn't show.

Comment: You don't need to set `EntityState.Modified` manually. "already tracked" means that somewhere is a relationship connecting your entity to something that was updated previously. Perhaps there is a navigation property somewhere that EF has decided must exist, but hard to say more without your model and EF modelbuilder code.

Comment: The last edit sounds defensive. It's not tricky at all, all my DI-enabled console apps "just work". Variants 1) and 2) should both work, 1 is suboptimal. Nothing in your question suggests why it doesn't work for you. Without adding more information (or link the complete github project), there is little anyone can do to help you. You mention "default DI scope" which sounds weird, try to expand on what you mean by that. "this error occurs "sometimes", but quite often" -> strong smell of a race condition, and scope lifetime handling seems like prime suspect.

Comment: it was defensive :D It seems like people voting to close the question on wrong assumptions

...  the default life time for DbContext is scoped.

Comment: Oh, you mean default lifetime of dbcontext DI registration (scoped). Shouldn't be a problem by itself, scoped services work fine in console apps, as long as you create scope for them. Which is a part you didn't show.